# DataGrab and Matrix importing issue (no data imported into Matrix Field)

Tags: matrix, datagrab

I'm trying to import data from a CSV into Matrix (2.5.6) using DataGrab (1.7.7) and I'm getting the following errors repeated for each row of data within the CSV

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_settings
Filename: fieldtypes/datagrab_matrix.php
Line Number: 114
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: fieldtypes/datagrab_matrix.php
Line Number: 136
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: field_settings
Filename: fieldtypes/datagrab_matrix.php
Line Number: 372
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: fieldtypes/datagrab_matrix.php
Line Number: 397
```

At the end of the import I should have a single entry with 30 rows in the matrix component, sadly the matrix field is completely empty.

I recognise that the Matrix field import is listed as beta within the tool itself but in this instance it isn't working.

Thanks for any thoughts / help / works for me on this.

Comment: I always prefer importing matrix content with DataGrab in XML format. Is it possible to convert over to XML and import in?

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to quickly convert the test csv file I have to XML and see how that works out, if it resolves the issue then I'll chuck it back at the data provider.  Thanks

Comment: I'm also in conversation with the developer about this issue (http://brandnewbox.co.uk/forums/viewthread/855/)

Answer (score 1):

After giving Andrew (the developer of Datagrab) the relevant access he was able to resolve the issue but suggested it might be another add on clashing with Datagrab.

I found the problem to be http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master removing the channel from Title Master resolved the issue and the data imported into the channel and Matrix fields as intended.